# SQL PIVOT multiple columns

Tags: sql-server, pivot

so this:

[image]

so I need:
[image]
any suggestions?

Comment: The point where I think this question is different is that there are multiple columns to pivot on. But the pattern in my answer should be able to be applied.

Answer (score 1):

Use a Matrix control in SSRS.

But in T-SQL:

You want a row per `ID` so you'll need `GROUP BY ID`

In the first column you want a `time` value where the activity is A, so use: `MAX(CASE WHEN Activity = 'Activity A' THEN time END)`

And then apply the pattern for all the others.